# How do you get a clickable path to a file or folder?

Tags: macos, email, automator, copy-paste, path

I already saw a lot of questions and answers about how to copy the path of a file or folder using Automator.

I personally like to use the copy option under the action menu on top of your finder because this will give you a path which can be used as a link:

[image: Finder Screenshot]

You can paste this link in your e-mail. It's clickable so the receiver can click it and the exact location of the file will be opened.

But... does anybody know if there is a way to copy this path automatically in an e-mail message using Automator? 
I know how to create an e-mail in Automator but I can only copy the 'readable' path in it, which can't be clicked...

Comment: Isn't that is the path on your mac and it won't be the path on anyone else?

Comment: True, if you point out a local file. In the company I work at we all work on a server with millions of files in a lot of folders and subfolders. If I copy the normal way, I get spaces. The above way of copying gives me %20 instead which makes it clickable.

Comment: The difference:     

smb://nl01vf006/Marketing/Season 15 1/15172 Franchise requests/15172004 South Africa New Arrivals Event evite/WKT/JPG/15172004 South Africa New Arrivals Event e-vite 1.jpg

Comment: and: 

file://localhost/Volumes/Marketing/Season%2015%201/15172%20Franchise%20requests/15172004%20South%20Africa%20New%20Arrivals%20Event%20evite/WKT/JPG/15172004%20South%20Africa%20New%20Arrivals%20Event%20e-vite%201.jpg

Comment: @Maartenvant - I used to use this method to copy file paths in Mac all the time and worked great. But I recently upgraded to MacOS HighSierra and my Outlook to V16.11 (I probably hadn't upgraded for 2 years before this). Now this copy paste feature no longer works :( Any updates on how to make it work again?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using a scripting language to do this. I've created a simple JavaScript for Automation program that can do the job (it can also be fairly easily replicated in AppleScript):

```
finder = Application('Finder')
finder.includeStandardAdditions = true
file = finder.chooseFile()
path = String(file).replace(' ', '%20')
```

You could then use the `path` variable to create a new OutgoingMessage in Mail.

Alternatively, you could use this as a "Run Javascript" block in Automator, then use its result in a New Mail Message (in which case you would need to append `return path` to then end of the script).